# What does "Documents and Synchronization" mean in cellular data usage?

Tags: ios, cellular-data

Mobile data usage in iOS 14.5 settings keeps showing "System services" as using ridiculous amounts of data — this time "Documents and Synchronization" has used 2 GB for no discernible reason.

**What does "Documents and Synchronization" mean? What does it include?** It's pretty vague.

I simply don't do any heavy transfers to/from iCloud. I don't upload files to iCloud Drive, I don't use iCloud Photo Library nor any other photos related cloud feature, I don't keep music on iCloud, I don't have iCloud backup enabled, messages on iCloud has consumed the same size for years, but still this anonymous entry finds a way to consume 2 GB since the beginning of the month.

As for third party apps, none take any iCloud space worth mentioning. In fact, the entire contents of iCloud is only 1.6 GB.

**Update:** also iCloud Drive is not permitted to use mobile data at all.

I have already disabled Safari from using iCloud since "Safari Services" was doing the same thing to my mobile data earlier, but which iCloud feature do I need to turn off this time?

Comment: Some App Store data in ICloud. Did you check on iCloud Drive if you have application folders.

Comment: @PtitXav Yes, I did check. As I mentioned, none worth mentioning, but to give you an idea the worst offender is WhatsApp at 90 MB which is an app that *hasn't been installed for years*. The next third party contender consumes 4 MB...

Comment: Seen on another forum, there is a parameter to authorise cellular data in case of weak wifi signal. Be sure to disable it.

Comment: @PtitXav Thanks for the suggestion, although it is already off. I also imagine the data consumption will still be attributed to the respective app, which would still beg the same question: what does this cellular data entry represent?

Comment: Found this [theead](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6699314) on apple forum